# Best way to have animated background in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have seen some similar questions asked but no definitive answer.
I have a background image that I'm using for my main menu for a cocos2d game.  I plan to have it animated but not sure what is the most efficient way to do this.  One idea was to have multiple images to create the animation but I was thinking this may take up too much memory as each image would be quite big.

The other idea was having one background image as a sprite and then having child sprites of that image that are animated with ccaction.  The only thing is I may not be able to create such an elaborate animation if I do this.

I just wanted to get some feedback on this to see what would be the best approach.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a frame-by-frame animation of the whole screen would make your app size litteraly explode.

You should definitely go with your 2nd idea, i.e have different sprites for each animated component and use actions to animate them.

Check out [CocosBuilder](http://cocosbuilder.com): it provides a nice UI for designing such complex animations